# how javascript's animation works in google T-rex game?

Tags: javascript, animation

I'm wondring how t-rex game (google) actually animate with this [code](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/master/components/neterror/resources/offline.js).
Specifically, i had a look at the code and trying to understand how it animate.
 As far as i know, the update function(which is prototype in the source file) should be called over and over to make animation happen.
 However, i can't see anything that calls update function several times. 
And this source code is written with self-invoking function and there is a constructor called Runner at the beginning of the code. My question is does this constructor get called by itself?

To sum up my question,

With this code, **can anyone explain how animation actually work? is there any way for Runner's prototype( you can find it if you see the source code on links) to be called from browser or whatever..?**

And, **when self invoking function get started by itself, does constructor or inner function get called at the same time..?**

Thanks in advance plz someone shed light on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I figured it out.

So the update method actually calls itself recursively in a fairly roundabout way.

At the end up update you have these statements

```
if (!this.crashed) {
  this.tRex.update(deltaTime);
  this.raq();
}
```

The magic happens with the `raq` method. It's what calls the update method again. `requestAnimationFrame` is a browser method that requests a reanimation of the screen with the callback being called before the animation is done. Therefore, the `update` method is called again, which lets it call `raq` again which calls `update` again, etc...

```
raq: function() {
    if (!this.drawPending) {
        this.drawPending = true;
        this.raqId = requestAnimationFrame(this.update.bind(this));
    }
},
```

For reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame

On how the application actually starts, I think it has to do with annotations and the closure compiler. The @export annotation on Runner means that an instance of it is getting created by the Self Invoker Function.

Then the constructor calls `loadImages` which calls `init` which calls `update`

Comment: Davis, Thank you for clear explanation. I was so touched. Btw, I just wanted to ask quick question while im reading the code more. i thought u might know so i decided to ask it here so plz forgive me for this. Question is : there is a another prototype called "handleEvent". can you explain why it uses closure and what is the benefit of using it in this context. And why it uses also self-invoking function as well.